# Running Nodejs application and wordpress in same server

Tags: server, apache2, webserver, amazon-aws, node-js

I am using one EC2 instance of AWS, I have two domains which I will connect with ec2 elastic ip but one domain will have wordpress running on it and other will have nodejs application running on it. My question is can I run both nodejs and wordpress application using apache web server

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server

Comment: @AbuNooh Thank You!